# What is wrong with this derivation?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $n$ distinct sets, and each sets has many similar objects. I have to choose $r$ objects from these sets. Any number (including all $r$) of objects can be picked up from any set. My solution goes like this:

1. Take $r$ objects from each of the $n$ sets and put them together. So now we have a set with $nr$ objects with $r$ objects of each kind.
2. Choose $r$ objects from this set. This can be done in $\dfrac{{}^{nr}C_r}{(r!)^n}$ ways. The denominator is there to make for the equivalence of $n$ sets of $r$ objects.

This derivation is wrong as can be verified with a small example. According to a book the correct answer is ${}^{n+r-1}C_r$. This formula gives the correct answer.

What is wrong with this derivation and how can the correct answer be derived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is your symmetry factor. You should only divide by the factorial of the objects used which is a varying number.

One way to obtain the correct answer is to place the $r$ objects in a line and then distribute $n-1$ separators between them. Objects between two separators will then come from the same set. It remains to count the ways to mix $r$ objects and $n-1$ separators which is the binomial coefficient.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand The second paragraph. Which `r` objects are you talking about?

Comment: The $r$ objects that you want to choose. You can think of choosing them by labelling them with labels from 1 to $n$, and this is done by separating them into $n$ groups by $n-1$ separators.